# How to dynamically select the next page of a wizard

Tags: java, eclipse, wizard, jface

I need to create a wizard in which the first page allows the user to select the type of the element to create, and the following pages create and set-up the selected type. In several aspects it is similar to the standard New Wizard (File->new...) but I need more control on what's happening.

How can I do that? Does there is any tutorial about that?

Answer (score 3):

I see three options on how to achieve this:

1. Override the `getNextPage(...)` function of `Wizard`

   *or*
2. Add the remaining pages to the wizard just-in-time. That is, after the user has selected what type of element to create.

   *or*
3. Make the remaining wizard pages dynamic in such a way that they have different contents depending on what kind of element is being created

I recommend the first option.

Comment: Hi, I tried both your 1st and 2nd option, while the 3rd is not applicable to my scenario (I use several factories and I cannot replace the content of a wizard page). With the first option, I had problems with the finish button. In particular, I needed a way to disable the finish button while the user is in the first page, and enable it when the second page is Ok. The implementation using your second option had some problems with the back button because you can only add pages to the wizard and you cannot remove them.

Comment: (Anyway, I'll work on the first option, but I hoped that there was something more advanced.)